# How do I add the change of one cell to another cell in Excel, without VBA?

Tags: excel, cell

So I have a cell, say A1. It contains a text. If this text is changed in any way, the cell A2 will contain the change. If it is changed again, the change will simply be added to cell A2 in the following manner.

A1: Never
A2: Never

A1: Gonna
A2: Never, Gonna

A1: Let
A2: Never, Gonna, Let

A1: You
A2: Never, Gonna, Let, You

A1: Down
A2: Never, Gonna, Let, You, Down

Basically the change to the cell gets added to the other together with a comma.
Oh yeah, and I need to manage this **without** VBA. Any way I can do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not possible without vba.  A formula will not hold the old data, but is live information only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could it without VBA.

First Enable Iterative Calculation in Excel.

Go to **File ---> Optoins ----> Formulas and under Calculation options check Enable iterative calculation.**

[image]

Now, add this formula to A2, while A1 is blank.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2 & IF(A1 <>"",",","") &A1,"0,","")
```

And thats all, start typing in A1 and you will see a running sentence in A2.

[image]

so to answer your question :

> Oh yeah, and I need to manage this without VBA. Any way I can do
>   this?

Yes, we can do this.

**But should you do this?** recommendation is no. Use VBA as suggested by Scott and Gary's Student. This formula with circular refernce will work and give you expected result, but as soon as you start adding other formulas with circular ref, your sheet will become more hard to maintain. iterations are tricky to understand and control and for text handling, certainly an overkill

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I am working on a project for school where we are not allowed to use VBA, and since I am not planning on using any other circular references, this will do very well.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that uses *VBA*.  If more proficient user comes up with a non-VBA solution, ignore this answer.  Place the following Event Macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, A2 As Range, rint As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set A2 = Range("A2")
    Set rint = Intersect(Target, A1)
    If rint Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If A2 = "" Then
            A2 = A1
        Else
            A2 = A2 & ", " & A1
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**